# Checking if a string array contains a value, and if so, getting its position

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have this string array:

```
string[] stringArray = { "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4" };
string value = "text3";
```

I would like to determine if `stringArray` contains `value`. If so, I want to locate its position in the array.

I don't want to use loops. Can anyone suggest how I might do this?

Answer (score 376, accepted):

You could use the [Array.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof.aspx) method:

```
string[] stringArray = { "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4" };
string value = "text3";
int pos = Array.IndexOf(stringArray, value);
if (pos > -1)
{
    // the array contains the string and the pos variable
    // will have its position in the array
}
```

Comment: ...And I've been using foreach for months.  BTW is this computationally faster than BLUEPIXY's answer?  Or slower?

Comment: Does `Array.IndexOf` care about capitalization? Does `"text1" == "TEXT1"`?

Comment: `Array.IndexOf` returns `−1` only if the index is 0-bounded. This case would break, so be aware! `var a = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int),new int[] { 2 }, new int[] { 1 }); a.SetValue(1, 1); Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(a, 26)); // 0`

Comment: This is useful if you're looking for an exact match. However, this might be useful if you don't care about case: [How to add a case-insensitive option to Array.IndexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935161/how-to-add-a-case-insensitive-option-to-array-indexof)

Answer (score 84):

```
var index = Array.FindIndex(stringArray, x => x == value)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it allows one to pass in a lambda to do more complicated things like Array.FindIndex(array, x => x.StartsWith("insert string here"))

Comment: But that is not what the question is asking for. The question asks how do you find a known value from an array.

Comment: @KarlGjertsen _I want to locate its position in the array_

Comment: This is very useful though, being able to do something like an x.ToUpper() was pretty beneficial to me.

Answer (score 49):

We can also use `Exists`:

```
string[] array = { "cat", "dog", "perl" };

// Use Array.Exists in different ways.
bool a = Array.Exists(array, element => element == "perl");
bool c = Array.Exists(array, element => element.StartsWith("d"));
bool d = Array.Exists(array, element => element.StartsWith("x"));
```

Comment: Clean and simple answer

Comment: How do I check individual values? When I tried checking a char array for a char, I got a message that `char` can't be converted to `System.Predicate<char>`

Comment: `Array.Exists(array, element => element.Equals("perl", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` If you're concerned with caps.

Answer (score 15):

EDIT: I hadn't noticed you needed the position as well. You can't use `IndexOf` directly on a value of an array type, because it's implemented explicitly. However, you can use:

```
IList<string> arrayAsList = (IList<string>) stringArray;
int index = arrayAsList.IndexOf(value);
if (index != -1)
{
    ...
}
```

(This is similar to calling [`Array.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187.aspx) as per Darin's answer - just an alternative approach. It's not clear to me why [`IList<T>.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w0148af.aspx) *is* implemented explicitly in arrays, but never mind...)

Comment: how do I find the possition of the world in the array using Contains?

Comment: Is there a possiblity to check a string item in string array A exists in another string array B?

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan: It's not clear what you're asking - whether the two arrays have *any* items in common? One *specific* item? (In the latter case, the fact that it's also in an array is irrelevant.)

Comment: I was trying to answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22812525/1559213 . I struck up to return true/false for Html.CheckBox line. Actually there is a months array and also the model which has some months. If Model month is present in months array we need to return true. Thanks for rocket response :)

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan: Well that sounds like `if (months.Contains(model.Month))`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used `model.contains(months[x])` based on your input

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Array.IndexOf()` - note that it will return -1 if the element has not been found and you have to handle this case.

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(stringArray, value);
```

Answer (score 5):

you can try like this...you can use Array.IndexOf() , if you want to know the position also

```
       string [] arr = {"One","Two","Three"};
       var target = "One";
       var results = Array.FindAll(arr, s => s.Equals(target));
```

Answer (score 5):

Use System.Linq

```
stringArray.Contains(value3);
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

IMO the best way to check if an array contains a given value is to use `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>.Contains(T item)` method the following way:

```
((IList<string>)stringArray).Contains(value)
```

Complete code sample:

```
string[] stringArray = { "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4" };
string value = "text3";
if (((IList<string>)stringArray).Contains(value)) Console.WriteLine("The array contains "+value);
else Console.WriteLine("The given string was not found in array.");
```

`T[]` arrays privately implement a few methods of `List<T>`, such as Count and Contains. Because it's an explicit (private) implementation, you won't be able to use these methods without casting the array first. This doesn't only work for strings - you can use this trick to check if an array of any type contains any element, as long as the element's class implements IComparable.

Keep in mind not all `IList<T>` methods work this way. Trying to use `IList<T>`'s Add method on an array will fail.

Comment: Yours is basically the same answer as Priyank's. It doesn't give the index of the element which is what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @reggaeguitar Agree with you there!

Comment: It's the solution _I_ was looking for, even though it doesn't completely answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it looks up for the index containing this element, and it sets the index number as the int, then it checks if the int is greater then -1, so if it's 0 or more, then it means it found such an index - as arrays are 0 based.

```
string[] Selection = {"First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"};
string Valid = "Third";    // You can change this to a Console.ReadLine() to 
    //use user input 
int temp = Array.IndexOf(Selection, Valid); // it gets the index of 'Valid', 
                // in our case it's "Third"
            if (temp > -1)
                Console.WriteLine("Valid selection");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not a valid selection");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string x ="Hi ,World";
string y = x;
char[] whitespace = new char[]{ ' ',\t'};          
string[] fooArray = y.Split(whitespace);  // now you have an array of 3 strings
y = String.Join(" ", fooArray);
string[] target = { "Hi", "World", "VW_Slep" };

for (int i = 0; i < target.Length; i++)
{
    string v = target[i];
    string results = Array.Find(fooArray, element => element.StartsWith(v, StringComparison.Ordinal));
    //
    if (results != null)
    { MessageBox.Show(results); }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an extension method for re-use.

```
   public static bool InArray(this string str, string[] values)
    {
        if (Array.IndexOf(values, str) > -1)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

How to call it:

```
string[] stringArray = { "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4" };
string value = "text3";
if(value.InArray(stringArray))
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Where is the `position` that the OP is asking for?

Answer (score -3):

```
string[] strArray = { "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4" };
string value = "text3";

if(Array.contains(strArray , value))
{
    // Do something if the value is available in Array.
}
```

Comment: It gives error: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'contains'.

Answer (score -4):

The simplest and shorter method would be the following.

```
string[] stringArray = { "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4" };
string value = "text3";

if(stringArray.Contains(value))
{
    // Do something if the value is available in Array.
}
```

Comment: The question was about finding the position of an item in an array.... With the `Contains` method you don't have this information