# Find array index by ignorecase

Tags: c#, arrays, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a case-insensitive option to Array.IndexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935161/how-to-add-a-case-insensitive-option-to-array-indexof)

```
int index1 = Array.IndexOf(myKeys, "foot");
```

Example I have `FOOT` in my array list, but it will return value of `index1 = -1`.

How can I find index of `foot` by ignoring the case?

Answer (score 17):

By using `FindIndex` and a little lambda.

```
var ar = new[] { "hi", "Hello" };
var ix = Array.FindIndex(ar, p => p.Equals("hello", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an `IComparer<string>` class:

```
public class CaseInsensitiveComp: IComparer<string>
{    
    private CaseInsensitiveComparer _comp = new CaseInsensitiveComparer();
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return _comp.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

Then performing a BinarySearch on the **sorted** array:

```
var myKeys = new List<string>(){"boot", "FOOT", "rOOt"};
IComparer<string> comp = new CaseInsensitiveComp();

myKeys.Sort(comp);

int theIndex = myKeys.BinarySearch("foot", comp);
```

Usually most effective on bigger arrays, preferably static.