# Is it possible to make IndexOf case-insensitive in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, indexof, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I've got a problem searching an INDEX in an array made up by query sessions command in a terminal server.

This is the problematic script:

```
# Array of logged users in terminal servers 
$a=Get-RDUsersession -CollectionName "BLABLA" -ConnectionBroker BLABLA.BLA.BL

# Array of all users with two columns from active directory
$b=Get-ADUser -filter * -properties TelephoneNumber,SamAccountName
```

Now imagine logging in the terminal server using the account name `TEST` instead of `test`.

If I do:

```
$c = $b[$b.SamAccountName.indexof("test")].TelephoneNumber
```

then I don't get the telephone number.

I think that's because of the case sensitivity, isn't it? If I type `TEST` in the search command, I get the correct number.

Is there any simple way to solve this problem and make the search of the index case-insensitive?
I've read about using the method `[StringComparison]"CurrentCultureIgnoreCase"`, but it seems not working with array.

Thanks.

Comment: You might also be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935161/how-to-add-a-case-insensitive-option-to-array-indexof

Answer (score 4):

Since $b is an Object[] type, then you would probably want to do a Where-Object.

```
$b | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Samaccountname -like '*Smith*'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'telephoneNumber'
```

That being said, an array in Powershell can be indexed case-insensitively if it is converted to a [Collections.Generic.List[Object]] type.

```
$b = [Collections.Generic.List[Object]]$b
$b.FindIndex( {$args[0].sAMAccountName -eq 'test'} )
```

Note that pulling every single user object in AD and filtering using where-object or index matching can be very slow. You can instead Get-ADUser as needed or pull all ADusers using a filter that pulls only the users returned in $a.

If you insist on having all ADUsers in one spot with one pull, consider looping over the list once to make a hash lookup so you can easily index the hash value.

```
#Create account lookup hash
$accountlookup = @{}
foreach ($element in $accounts) {
  $accountlookup[$element.SamAccountName] = $element 
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use .ToLower() method on your string before indexOf

$c = $b[$b.SamAccountName.ToLower().indexof("test")].TelephoneNumber