# Checking if string contains one of the array values using C# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, arrays

i have `string[] srt={"t","n","m"}`

i need to know if the user input contain one of the values in str and print that value

i try this code but its not work with me

```js
string str = Textbox.Text;
    string s = "";
    string[] a = {"m","t","n"};
        
        if (str.Contains(a.ToString()))
        {
            s = s + a;
        }

        else
        {
            s = s + "there is no match in the string";
        }

        Label1.Text = s;
```

Comment: the sippet doesn't run!!

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, because it seems to be the user input will be in `str`, so it seems you are trying to check if the user input contains something from `a`, correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using C# to check if string contains a string in string array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912476/using-c-sharp-to-check-if-string-contains-a-string-in-string-array)

Comment: YES THAT WHAT I WANT TO DO

Answer (score 3):

You need to search array for string value you have in str so

```
if (str.Contains(a.ToString()))
```

Would be

```
if(a.Contains(s))
```

Your code would be

```
if (a.Contains(str))
{
    s = s + "," + a;
}
else
{
     s = s + "there is no match in the string";
}

Label1.Text = s;
```

As a **additional note** you should use meaning full names instead of `a`, `s`.

You can also use conditional [operator ?:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) to make it more simple.

```
string matchResult = a.Contains(s) ? "found" : "not found"
```

Answer (score 2):

Converting the array to a string isn't what is needed. If you don't care which character matched, use `Any()`

```
var s = a.Any(anA => str.Contains(anA))
    ? "There is a match"
    : "There is no match in the string";
```

And if you want the matches:

```
var matches = a.Where(anA => str.Contains(anA));
var s = matches.Any()
    ? "These Match: " + string.Join(",", matches)
    : "There is no match in the string";
```

Answer (score 1):

see [Checking if a string array contains a value, and if so, getting its position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867377/checking-if-a-string-array-contains-a-value-and-if-so-getting-its-position)
You could use the Array.IndexOf method:

```
string[] stringArray = { "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4" };
string value = "text3";
int pos = Array.IndexOf(stringArray, value);
if (pos >- 1)
{
    // the array contains the string and the pos variable
    // will have its position in the array
}
```