# If Function to hide column in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio, parameters, lookup-tables, iif

I'm trying to write a vbscript iif statement for visual studio which reads the value of a parameter and hides a column based on that parameter. The issue I am having is the parameter allows multi values so not sure how to word the iif statement.

I have a lookup called lookup.include which does this :

```
SELECT 'All' AS [TEXT] , '1,2,3,4' AS [VALUE]
UNION 
SELECT 'Welcome_Call' AS [TEXT], '1' AS [VALUE]
UNION
SELECT 'Month_One_Call'  AS [TEXT], '2' AS [VALUE]
UNION
SELECT 'Month_two_Call'   AS [TEXT], '3' AS [VALUE]
UNION
SELECT 'Month_six_Call'    AS [TEXT], '4' AS [VALUE]
```

This is a multi value parameter and allows the user to chose more than one value.

So I have a drop down list with the options below (ignore names)

So in my look up This is assigned a number value.

[image]

I have tried to do an vbscript if statement which says

```
iif (paramter.value <>  1   ,false,true)
```

which works if only Welcome call is selected , but wont if more than one option is selected.

What I need is basically to write an iif statement to test if the value I want is present in the options chosen.

E.g, if user selects Values 1,2,3 the if statement picks up that one is present.

Like the IN function in SQL , just the vb script equivalent

Comment: c# : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-parse-strings-using-string-split and  `foreach` ,`switch`

Comment: sorry meant to say this is in sql , need the vb script statement for it

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, can you share your vb-code what you have tried?

Comment: updated with more detail

Answer (score 0):

From your statement:

> This is a multi value parameter and allows the user to chose more than
>   one value.

It looks like you have a control like `ListBox` or `CheckedListBox` that display all the above `UNION` values in it. For such case you can get selected values from control itself OR you can maintain the selection in a string array. Later on you can use [`Array.IndexOf(stringArray, value)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867377/checking-if-a-string-array-contains-a-value-and-if-so-getting-its-position) to see if your desired `value` exists in the collection `stringArray` of selected items.