# How do I compare a string with a string array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Yes I'm a beginner and maybe it is not possible, but is there anything I can do to test if a string is equal to a string array?

```
        string speech = e.Result.Text;
        String[] greeting = new string[2] { "hello", "hi" };

            if (speech == greeting) 
            {
                James.SpeakAsync("Hi");
            }
```

Comment: Do you except that if `speech` is equal to "hello" or "hi" , result should be `true`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867377/checking-if-a-string-array-contains-a-value-and-if-so-getting-its-position

Answer (score 0):

So you got a string array of 2 names

```cs
string[] arrayOfNames { "Jon", "Jack" }
string jon = "Jon";

/*In order to check if the name you have in your var is same as in the list you can do a foreach loop*/

foreach(var name in arrayOfNames)
{
//Check each key if we have name with jon
    if (name == jon) Print("Succes");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq extension methods is best way for this.

```
using System.Linq;
...
if(greeting.Contains(speech) {
   // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method: Linq**

If you already have Linq imported, then you can just use Linq:

```
string speech = e.Result.Text;
string[] greeting = new string[2] { "hello", "hi" };
if (greeting.Contains(speech))
{
     James.SpeakAsync("Hi");
}
```

**Method: IndexOf**

If you aren't already using Linq, check the index of the string using Array.IndexOf.  The result will be -1 if there is no match.

```
string speech = e.Result.Text;
string[] greeting = new string[2] { "hello", "hi" };
if (Array.IndexOf(greeting, speech) > -1)
{
     James.SpeakAsync("Hi");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ methods: **Contains() or Any()**.

You can check if the array contains the given string as follows:

```
string speech = e.Result.Text;
        var greeting = new string { "hello", "hi" };

            if (greeting.Contains(speech)) 
            {
                James.SpeakAsync("Hi");
            }
```

Or

```
string speech = e.Result.Text;
        var greeting = new string { "hello", "hi" };

            if (greeting.Any(g=>g.Equals(speech))) 
            {
                James.SpeakAsync("Hi");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you have some string `speech` and you want to know if that string is equal to a string in your array `greeting`. (I based this assumption off the fact you want to accept some speech and equate it to a variety of greetings - what you are calling "equality" here is really that the speech belongs to a set of greetings.)

In that case you will need to *loop* over the array values and compare them one-by-one with your original string. I suggest using a [for loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for).

For example, let's assume `speech` is `"hi"` here:

```
    string speech = "hi";
    String[] greeting = new string[2] { "hello", "hi" };

    for (int i = 0; i < greeting.Length; i++) {
      if (speech == greeting[i]) 
      {
          Console.WriteLine ("found string in array");
      }
    }
```

Notice I use `greeting.Length` to get the size of the array (which is `2`). (See: [Array.Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length?view=netcore-3.1#System_Array_Length).)

Also notice that I use `greeting[i]` to access the ith string of the array.

`i` starts at 0, so the first string in the array is fetched with `greeting[0]` gives you the first element of the array, `"hello"` in this case.

`"hello"` does not equal `"hi"` so nothing happens, and the loop starts again with `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`.

With `i = 1` now, `greeting[1]` gives us `"hi"`, which *is* the same as `speech`, and we get the console message I wrote.

Is this what you were looking for?

Since you're a beginner, I would advise spending some time reading the docs on Arrays: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array

Be sure to experiment with examples to get yourself familiar.

Once you are comfortable with loops, a more elegant solution would be to use [Array.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof), as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7867403/14197634) to a similar question.